# JS validation for checkbox not working when put name []

Tags: javascript, validation

I have an JS validation for checkbox.

```
function ActionCcdCheck (theForm)
{
    if (theForm.ccd_chk.checked)
    {
        theForm.ccd_pos[0].className = 'part';
        theForm.ccd_pos[1].className = 'part';
        theForm.ccd_pos[2].className = 'part';

        theForm.ccd_pos[0].disabled  = false;
        theForm.ccd_pos[0].checked  = false;
        theForm.ccd_pos[1].disabled  = false;
        theForm.ccd_pos[1].checked  = false;
        theForm.ccd_pos[2].disabled  = false;
        theForm.ccd_pos[2].checked  = false;
    }
    else
    {
        theForm.ccd_pos[0].disabled  = true;
        theForm.ccd_pos[1].disabled  = true;
        theForm.ccd_pos[2].disabled  = true;
    }
}
```

The checkbox

```
<td colspan="1" rowspan="2" width="35">CCD</td>
<td>Check</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ccd_chk" value="yes" class="part" onclick="ActionCcdCheck (this.form);" onkeypress="FocusChange (this.form, 5, 4);"/> Yes</td>
<tr>
<td>Position</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="ccd_pos[]" value="front" class="part" onkeypress="FocusChange (this.form, 6, 3);"/> Front
<input type="checkbox" name="ccd_pos[]" value="back" class="part" onkeypress="FocusChange (this.form, 7, 2);"/> Back
<input type="checkbox" name="ccd_pos[]" value="fb" class="part" onkeypress="FocusChange (this.form, 8, 1);"/> FB
</td>

<tr>
```

Now I am facing problem when I put checkbox name like this name="ccd_pos[]". The JS validation not working. I use that because I want to submit multiple value of checkbox.

So anyone can give me an suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: You're probably better off looping through the checkbox elements within the form instead of looking at the nth element. e.g. in jquery $(input:checkbox).each ( function () {
// blah;
});

Comment: Just a quick note that @Duniyadnd's example code is missing quotes around the selector; it should be `$('input:checkbox')...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

```
theForm.ccd_pos[0]
```

is looking for a `ccd_pos` property of the form, there isn't one. What you need is something like:

```
theForm['ccd_pos[]'][0]
```

as form controls with the same name will be returned as a collection, so:

```
theForm['ccd_pos[]']
```

returns a [collection](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#collections) of the three controls with name `ccd_pos[]`. Then use normal index names to access the various members of the collection.

Note that in javascript, [dot notation is a shortcut to formal property access](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10) and can only be used where the name is complies with the rules for [identifiers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6). Otherwise, you must use square bracket (formal) notation.

So your code can be something like:

```
var box, boxes = theForm.['ccd_pos[]'];

for (var i=0, iLen=boxes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  box = boxes[i];

  if (theForm.ccd_chk.checked) {
    box.className = 'part';
    box.disabled  = false;
    box.checked   = false;
  } else {
    box.disabled  = true;
    // and probably
    box.className = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Very cool. Thanks now my code is running well. :) Cheers @RobG